# How to render a page in pug template engine in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug, template-engine

I want to render a page when I click on `Signin`. I use a `Service Oriented Architecture`, in which I use  the Pug Template Engine for making an `Admin-Panel`. When I click on `SignIn`, it give the error below.

> {"error":{"message":"Not found"}}

I don't know where I made a mistake. Please help me.

Here is the `welcome.pug` code where there is a `Signin` link. Please see if I use the correct `url` or not.

```
  doctype html
  html(lang='{{ app()->getLocale() }}')
    head
      meta(charset='utf-8')
      meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
      meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
      title QuizLit
      // Fonts
      link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
      // Styles
      style.
        html, body {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #636b6f;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .full-height {
        height: 100vh;
        }
        .flex-center {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        }
        .position-ref {
        position: relative;
        }
        .top-right {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 18px;
        }
        .content {
        text-align: center;
        }
        .title {
        font-size: 84px;
        }
        .links > a {
        color: #636b6f;
        padding: 5px 25px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: .1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border: solid 1px #636b6f;
        border-radius: 50px;
        }
        .m-b-md {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
    body
      .flex-center.position-ref.full-height
        .content
          .title.m-b-md
            | Welcome to QuizLit
          .links
            a(href='/login') Sign in
```

Here is the structure of my code.

[image]

Here is the `login.pug` file

```
  include ../layout/main

  block content
  // Horizontal Form
  .login-box
    .login-logo
      a(href='/')
        b Admin
    // /.login-logo
    .login-box-body
      p.login-box-msg Sign in to start your session
      form(role='form', method='POST', action="/login")
        ul.text-danger
        .has-feedback(class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}")
          input#email.form-control(type='email', name='email', value=" ", placeholder='Email', required='')
          //- |         @if ($errors->has('email'))
          span.help-block
          //-   strong {{ $errors->first('email') }}
          //- |         @endif
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-envelope.form-control-feedback
        .has-feedback(class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}")
          input#password.form-control(type='password', name='password', placeholder='Password', required='')
          //- |             @if ($errors->has('password'))
          span.help-block
          //-   strong {{ $errors->first('password') }}
          //- |             @endif
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-lock.form-control-feedback
        .row
          .col-xs-7.col-xs-offset-1
            .checkbox.icheck
              label
                input(type='checkbox')
                |  Remember Me
          // /.col
          .col-xs-4
            button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.btn-flat(type='submit') Sign In
          // /.col

  //- | @section('page_specific_scripts')
  script(src="/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js")
  script.
    $(function () {
    $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%' /* optional */
    });
    });
```

And here is the `Api.js` code:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const adminAuthService = require('../service/adminAuthService');
const middlewares = require('../../../base/service/middlewares/accessControl');

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    adminAuthService.login(req.body)
        .then(data => {
            return res.send(data)
        }, err => next(err))
});

router.post("/createstudent", middlewares.assertUserIsAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    // router.post("/createstudent", (req, res, next) => {
    adminAuthService.signupStudent(req.body)
        .then(data => {
            return res.send(data)
        }, err => next(err))
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the `Index.js` file:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const adminRoutes = require("./admin");
const teacherRoutes = require("./teacher");
const appRoutes = require("./api");

router.use("/admin", adminRoutes);
router.use("/teacher", teacherRoutes);
router.use("/api", appRoutes);

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
   res.render('welcome');
})

module.exports = router
```

How should I separately define the `Web Routes` and `Api Routes` to use a Service Oriented Architecture in Node.js.

Comment: Seems like you have a lot going on in that `welcome.pug` file. Have you been able to narrow it down to a specific piece or is the entire file not working? Have you tried to render a simple `welcome.pug` with basic text eg. `h1 hello world`?

Comment: yes `welcome.pug` is render but `login.pug` is not render @Rastalamm

Comment: What are you using as a router? Is `/login` defined in your API?

Comment: I want when I click on `signin` on `welcome.pug` page it simply shows the `login.pug` page but it is not showing @Rastalamm

Comment: Please update the post with you login.pug file and with the API/routing definition that handles the loading of that page.

Comment: I edit My post Please see @Rastalamm

Comment: Any idea regarding this question @Stephen S

Comment: In your `index.js` file, how did you define the route for `Api.js`. Can you share that part of the code ?

Comment: ok i will add `index.js` also @StephenS

Comment: i update my post @StephenS check it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you do not have any `/login` route in the `index.js` file, so /login on the button would not work.

Secondly you don't seem to have any route handler which will render the `login.pug` file.
You can define this in the index.js file as a GET route

```
router.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
   res.render('login');
});
```

You can even keep this route handler in your `api.js` file in which case the effective route for the button would be

```
.links
   a(href='/api/login') Sign in
```

Comment: I use service oriented architecture and i made admin routes in which login api for admin @

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that may help is including a `POST` method request in your pug file.

At the moment, it appears you only have an API endpoint for `/login` listening for `POST` requests.

@stephen suggested you add a get route. If you don't want to or can't do that, you need to call `/login` with a `POST` method. Make sure to pass along the user information needed to authenticate them.